# What does Jodie mean with this sentence?

Tags: beyond-two-souls

In most endings of "Beyond - Two souls", a dream/vision is seen, showing basically

> the ghost apocalypse.

During this scene, she says (translated back into English by me):

> "I already died twice, I don't fear death."

What does she mean by that? When did this happen? And especially twice? One time might be in the final chapter where the player can decide between

> going back into life through the black wall and going to the "other side", through the bright blue one.

But I wouldn't really count that as

> dying, since she did **not** go to the light blue side in the apocalypse dream endings.

So what does she mean and what is the other time?

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/673021-beyond-two-souls/67464701) it's once in the homeless chapter (coma) and once in the final chapter (choose life or death). It's a possible explanation, but the people there just guessed.

Comment: Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20180430122127/https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/673021-beyond-two-souls/67464701